# Remove all rows preceding the first occurence null string in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
if(df_TA.index[df_TA['GSNumber'].isnull()][0] is None):
        df_TA=df_TA.loc[:]
    else:
        idx=df_TA.index[df_TA['GSN'].isnull()][0]
        df_TA=df_TA.loc[:idx-1]
I have many dataframes some of them contain null in a column followed by columns having value which is not required.I want to remove those extra occurence(remove all the rows of dataframe preceding the null column) after the first null value of the GNS column.
```

for eg.
Original Dataframe

```
GNS name
1    John
2    Lily

xyz   bcd
```

Output Dataframe:

```
 GNS     name
    1    John
    2    Lily
```

The code that I have written solves the problem but throws an exception

```
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

whenever the condition in the if condition holds true i.e. their are no rows with null values in the GNS col.Is there any way to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you there is problem you cannot select empty `idx`, so `if-else` is necessary. Also `df_TA.index[-1]` is for select all rows if no `NaN`s values.

```
idx = df_TA.index[df_TA['GSN'].isnull()]

idx = df_TA.index[-1] if idx.empty else idx[0] - 1
df_TA=df_TA.loc[:idx]
```